# Windows Driver IOCTL Code Bluescreens / Crashes The Computer

Tags: c++, c, windows, kernel, driver

I have a device driver which I utilize to read other process virtual memory from kernel space so I do not have to use functions like `ReadProcessMemory` or `WriteProcessMemory`.

This works fine when I use a structure as a medium to pass the arguments to the kernel via `DeviceIoControl`, but the driver crashes my computer when I use plain variables like an unsigned long.

### Here is an example of perfectly working code

**(Driver):**

```
#define IO_KERNEL_READ_REQUEST    CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, 0x0701, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_SPECIAL_ACCESS)

typedef struct _KERNEL_READ_REQUEST
{
    ULONG ProcessId;

    ULONG Address;
    ULONG Response;
    ULONG Size;

} KERNEL_READ_REQUEST, *PKERNEL_READ_REQUEST;

    if (ControlCode == IO_KERNEL_READ_REQUEST)
    {
        PKERNEL_READ_REQUEST ReadInput = (PKERNEL_READ_REQUEST)Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
        PKERNEL_READ_REQUEST ReadOutput = (PKERNEL_READ_REQUEST)Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;

        PEPROCESS Process;
        PsLookupProcessByProcessId(ReadInput->ProcessId, &Process);
        KeReadVirtualMemory(Process, ReadInput->Address, &ReadOutput->Response, ReadInput->Size);

        DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Read Params:  %lu, %#010x \n", ReadInput->ProcessId, ReadInput->Address);
        DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Value: %lu \n", ReadOutput->Response);

        status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
        bytesIO = sizeof(KERNEL_READ_REQUEST);
    }
```

**(Program):**

```
template <typename type>
type KernelRead(HANDLE hDriver, ULONG ProcessId, ULONG ReadAddress, SIZE_T ReadSize)
{
    if (hDriver == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return (type)false;

    DWORD Return;
    DWORD Bytes;
    KERNEL_READ_REQUEST  ReadRequest;

    ReadRequest.ProcessId = ProcessId;
    ReadRequest.Address = ReadAddress;
    ReadRequest.Size = ReadSize;

    if (DeviceIoControl(hDriver, IO_KERNEL_READ_REQUEST, &ReadRequest, sizeof(ReadRequest),
        &ReadRequest, sizeof(ReadRequest), &Bytes, NULL)) {
        return (type)ReadRequest.Response;
    }
    else
        return (type)false;
}
```

### This is what causes the problem

```
#define IO_KERNEL_GET_ID           CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, 0x0703, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_SPECIAL_ACCESS)
else if (ControlCode == IO_KERNEL_GET_ID)
{
    // ProcessId is an ULONG initialized at the driver entry
    PULONG OutPut = (PULONG)Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
    OutPut = &ProcessId;

    DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Kernel Get Id: %d \n", *OutPut);

    status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    bytesIO = sizeof(OutPut);
}

DWORD KernelGetProcessId(HANDLE hDriver)
{
    if (hDriver == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return false;
    ULONG Id;

    if (DeviceIoControl(hDriver, IO_KERNEL_GET_ID, &, sizeof(Id),
        &Id, sizeof(Id), 0, NULL))
        return Id;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Calling `KernelGetProcessId` crashes my driver and the whole computer, how can this be fixed? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: To my understanding, the communication from driver to usermode happens by copying the stack (?) or some items of the stack to the user space and then dealing with that. The fact that a global variable holds the value and I am just making a pointer to that & using it causes this because the global variable isn't located on the stack?

Comment: 1) you not check `InputBufferLength` and `OutputBufferLength` from `IrpSp->Parameters.DeviceIoControl`
2) you not check result of `PsLookupProcessByProcessId`
3) you not call `ObfDereferenceObject(Process)` 
4) `ULONG Address` must be `PVOID` or `ULONG_PTR` and are you check `Address` ?
5) you **must** analyze `memory.dmp` (or `pagefile.sys`) for view exactly where crash

Comment: @RbMm It was a dumb bug, already found the fix for it. Please check my answer

Comment: what you do - not fix

Comment: You haven't posted enough of the code.  For example, you set a variable named `OutPut` but we never see what it is used for.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Check [DeviceIoControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx). If lpOverlapped is NULL, lpBytesReturned cannot be NULL. Even when an operation returns no output data and lpOutBuffer is NULL, DeviceIoControl makes use of lpBytesReturned. After such an operation, the value of lpBytesReturned is meaningless.

Maybe it can be one of the reason.
Other issue which I an see is passing only &, you should pass ULONG variable in it.

Check some thing like this

```
DWORD KernelGetProcessId(HANDLE hDriver)
{
    if (hDriver == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return false;
    ULONG Id;
    DWORD Bytes;

    if (DeviceIoControl(hDriver, IO_KERNEL_GET_ID, &Id, sizeof(Id),
        &Id, sizeof(Id), &Bytes, NULL))
        return Id;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: _"Other issue which I an see is passing only &"_ tbf. How is that even compiling?

Comment: This does not work either, tried before. I think the problem resides in the kernel module code. Does no longer even cause a blue screen, just sets the processor to a shutdown state (tried on virtual & physical CPU).

Answer (score -1):

### The Issue:

Apparently the IOCTLs work by using the stack of both the
driver & the user program. To my understanding the stack of the
function calling DeviceIoControl() is copied to kernel space
and then dissected using the arguments of DeviceIoControl()
to know which stack variables we are working with & the buffer is
finally set to Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer.

After the IOCTL operation is finished on the kernel side,
IoCompleteRequest() is made which copies the stack of the
kernel module to userspace which then is again dissected to
the form we want it in.

(please correct me if I am wrong)

### The Solution:

The crash is caused by this code in the kernel module:

```
PULONG OutPut = (PULONG)Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
  OutPut = &ProcessId;
```

in which the global variable's address is set as the value of the output data.
Now when the stack is copied the address obviously does not point anywhere since
the "ProcessId" variable resides in 64 bit kernel space. This is my understanding of the problem.

This fixes the problem:

```
PULONG OutPut = (PULONG)Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
*OutPut = ProcessId;

DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Kernel Get Id: %d \n", *OutPut);

status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
bytesIO = sizeof(OutPut);
```

Comment: must be `bytesIO = sizeof(ULONG);` . your code is full nightmare

Comment: Nothing is copied from the kernel-mode stack.